# Android Emulator: Unfortunately Launcher has stopped

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

Since the last update of my Android Studio and my SDK packages, I get this error whenever I start the emulator. Please check the screen shot below.

[image]

My logcat reports these as error statement:

```
06-11 05:18:22.906  15313-15328/com.android.launcher E/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Out of memory on a 88955584-byte allocation.
06-11 05:18:22.956  15313-15328/com.android.launcher E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: launcher-loader
    Process: com.android.launcher, PID: 15313
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2115)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:755)
            at com.android.launcher2.IconCache.getFullResIcon(IconCache.java:74)
            at com.android.launcher2.IconCache.getFullResIcon(IconCache.java:113)
            at com.android.launcher2.IconCache.getFullResIcon(IconCache.java:98)
            at com.android.launcher2.IconCache.cacheLocked(IconCache.java:213)
            at com.android.launcher2.IconCache.getTitleAndIcon(IconCache.java:155)
            at com.android.launcher2.ApplicationInfo.<init>(ApplicationInfo.java:88)
            at com.android.launcher2.LauncherModel$LoaderTask.loadAllAppsByBatch(LauncherModel.java:1928)
            at com.android.launcher2.LauncherModel$LoaderTask.loadAndBindAllApps(LauncherModel.java:1820)
            at com.android.launcher2.LauncherModel$LoaderTask.run(LauncherModel.java:1134)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

The things I have tried out:
1. Deleted the emulator and created it fresh.
2. I found some answers on StackOverFlow talking about Hardware keys. did that too.

Comment: Try adding `largeHeap= "true"` in `Manifest`

Comment: Hey hrskrs, The above error is shown after the Emulator is just started not when I test any application on it.

Comment: Increase the memory size when you create a device in emulator then

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem
the problem was I use image on drawable that not support different
screen sizes as app icon so I changed to default icon of android studio and rebuilded the app and it now working
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEiTN.png)

Comment: Weird and strange. My problem got solved over the next update of the Android Emulator.